# Pandas how to group specific column rows together based off another columns values, and show rows that do not have a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For example, I have this dataFrame,

| plates | food |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | eggs |
| 1 | bacon |
| 2 | waffles |
| 2 | toast |
| 3 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | cereal |
| 4 | milk |

The result I want is...

| food |
| --- |
| eggs bacon |
| waffles toast |
| None |
| cereal milk |

This is what I have

```
result = df['food'].groupby(df['plates'].agg('sum')
```

but obviously the rows that aren't grouped are ignored. I want to find those values that do not have a group and fill those rows with Nan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming, the missing values in `food` column are empty strings (`""`):

Then:

```py
x = df.groupby("plates")["food"].agg(lambda x: " ".join(x).strip() or np.nan)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
plates
1       eggs bacon
2    waffles toast
3              NaN
4      cereal milk
Name: food, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.agg(list)` with `str.join()`

```
df.groupby('plates')['food'].agg(list).str.join(' ')


plates
1       eggs bacon
2    waffles toast
3              NaN
4      cereal milk
```